# Eliminar repetições e retornar ultimo registro PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Boa tarde,

Estou precisando fazer uma consulta para retornar a descrição dos registros de uma tabela, sendo que não pode haver repetições de ID (de outra tabela) e precisa ser o registro mais recente. Consulta:

[image: Consulta]

Registros retornados (alguns deles):

[image: Registros]

Estão vendo os "obraid" repetidos circulados em vermelho? Pois bem, preciso que retorne apenas um registro de um determinado "obraid" e este precisa ser o que tem a data mais recente, ou seja, estes que estão circulados em verde. Já tentei muita coisa e não consegui resolver. Alguém teria alguma ideia?

Comment: Utilize a cláusula GROUP BY o.id e a função de agregação max(m.data_movimentacao) e depois faça a junção para obter o status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode dividir a sua query em duas e com uma parte ,(obraid e data_movimentacao) fazer um group by pelo obraid e fazendo o max da data, funcionando como uma tabela na clausula FROM:

```sql
SELECT s.descricao, t.obraid, t.data_movimentacao
FROM (
SELECT o.id obraid, MAX(m.data_movimentacao) data_movimentacao
FROM obras.obra o
JOIN obras.movimento_obra m on o.id = m.obra_id
WHERE o.cliente_id = 106
GROUP BY o.id obraid ) t
JOIN obras.movimento_obra m on t.obraid = m.obra_id and t.data_movimentacao = m.data_movimentacao
JOIN obras.status_obra s on s.id = m.status_id
ORDER BY t.obraid
```

That query only work if the collumn data_movimentacao is a datetime type, but if it's a CHAR type, you can make the query like this:

```sql
SELECT s.descricao, t.obraid, t.data_movimentacao
FROM (
SELECT o.id obraid, to_char(MAX(to_date(m.data_movimentacao,'DD/MM/YYYY')) ,'DD/MM/YYYY') data_movimentacao
FROM obras.obra o
JOIN obras.movimento_obra m on o.id = m.obra_id
WHERE o.cliente_id = 106
GROUP BY o.id obraid ) t
JOIN obras.movimento_obra m on t.obraid = m.obra_id and t.data_movimentacao = m.data_movimentacao
JOIN obras.status_obra s on s.id = m.status_id
ORDER BY t.obraid
```

Comment: Agradeço a tentativa de solução, porém ainda deu erro, porque o "m" não é visível porque está dentro do select interno. 

ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "m"
LINE 10: JOIN obras.status_obra s on s.id = m.status_id.                                               

Tentei adicionar um "JOIN obras.movimento_obra m on t.id = m.obra_id" mas aí voltam todos os registros que são descartáveis da consulta.

Comment: Eu acrescentei um JOIN com a tabela "movimento_obra" novamente, mas na consulta externa, para assim ela fazer parte do contexto da consulta principal. Isso pode resolver o seu problema

Comment: Continuou dando erro, mas conseguir resolver de outra forma, sua solução me ajudou muito, obrigado!!